# How to Fix JQuery Error when displaying variant on Shopify Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, liquid

Hi I am trying to work out how I can fix a jquery error that I am getting when I try and display product prices for more than 2 products. Currently I have this working with 2 products (code showing 1 product code) but whenever I replicate the following code for a third product I get an Unresponsive script error and I am not sure if this is to do with memory limits in Shopify as works for 2 products.

My Code for 1 product in page.prices.liquid

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid_full">
    {% comment %}
      div class="grid__item large--two-thirds push--large--one-sixth" -- old one
    {% endcomment %}
  <div class="grid__item">

    {% for product in collections.leaflets.products %}
   {% for variant in product.variants %}


{% if forloop.index <=1 %}
<div id="temp_first" style="display:none;">
<div class="price"><a href="/products/leaflets?variant={{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.price | money | remove: '.00'}}</a></div>  

{% elsif forloop.index <13 %} 

<div class="price"><a href="/products/leaflets?variant={{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.price | money | remove: '.00'}}</a></div>

{% elsif forloop.index <=13 %}     
<div class="price"><a href="/products/leaflets?variant={{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.price | money | remove: '.00'}}</a></div>
</div>
{% elsif forloop.index ==14 %} 
<div id="temp_second" style="display:none;">
<div class="price"><a href="/products/leaflets?variant={{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.price | money | remove: '.00'}}</a></div>

{% elsif forloop.index <26 %} 
<div class="price"><a href="/products/leaflets?variant={{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.price | money | remove: '.00'}}</a></div>

{% elsif forloop.index ==26 %} 
<div class="price"><a href="/products/leaflets?variant={{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.price | money | remove: '.00'}}</a></div>
</div>

{% elsif forloop.index ==27 %}
<div id="temp_third" style="display:none;">
<div class="price"><a href="/products/leaflets?variant={{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.price | money | remove: '.00'}}</a></div>

{% elsif forloop.index <39 %}  
<div class="price"><a href="/products/leaflets?variant={{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.price | money | remove: '.00'}}</a></div>

{% elsif forloop.index ==39 %}  
<div class="price"><a href="/products/leaflets?variant={{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.price | money | remove: '.00'}}</a></div>
</div> 

{% elsif forloop.index ==40 %} 
<div id="temp_fourth" style="display:none;">
<div class="price"><a href="/products/leaflets?variant={{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.price | money | remove: '.00'}}</a></div>

{% elsif forloop.index <52 %} 
<div class="price"><a href="/products/leaflets?variant={{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.price | money | remove: '.00'}}</a></div>

{% elsif forloop.index ==52 %} 
<div class="price"><a href="/products/leaflets?variant={{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.price | money | remove: '.00'}}</a></div>       
    </div>  

{% endif %}

   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The following is the code within my page:

```
<script>// <![CDATA[
$i(document).ready(function () {
$("#price_first_row").html($("#temp_first").html());
$("#price_second_row").html($("#temp_second").html());
$("#price_third_row").html($("#temp_third").html());
$("#price_fourth_row").html($("#temp_fourth").html());
// ]]></script>

<div class="grid__item large prices-two">
<div class="prices-title blue">Product Name</div>
</div>
<div id="price_first_row" class="grid__item large prices-three"></div>
<div id="price_second_row" class="grid__item large prices-four"></div>
<div id="price_third_row" class="grid__item large prices-five"></div>
<div id="price_fourth_row" class="grid__item large prices-six"></div>
</div>
```

The only two lines that I have changed to add another product is:

```
{% for product in collections.leaflets.products %}
```

which is edited to change leaflets to 3rd product name and then changing the div ids to price_fifth_row etc.

The jquery error I get is the following:

[image]

At times this will say jquery.min.js:2 and at times jquery.min.js:3.

I would have shared a link for the site but this is locked with a password at the moment.

If somebody could please, would appreciate it.

Thanks

The following shows the script as part of another script hence the $i as was having jquery conflicts.

```
<script>// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#price_first_row").html($("#temp_first").html());
$("#price_second_row").html($("#temp_second").html());
$("#price_third_row").html($("#temp_third").html());
$("#price_fourth_row").html($("#temp_fourth").html());
    var carousel = $i("#owlCarousel-Prices");
  carousel.owlCarousel({
    items: 3,
    margin:10,
    navigation:true,
    autoHeight : true,
    autoPlay : 3000,
    navigationText: [
      "<i class='icon-chevron-left icon-white'><</i>",
      "<i class='icon-chevron-right icon-white'>></i>"
      ],
  });
});
// ]]></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your JavaScript code fixed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#price_first_row").html($("#temp_first").html());
        $("#price_second_row").html($("#temp_second").html());
        $("#price_third_row").html($("#temp_third").html());
        $("#price_fourth_row").html($("#temp_fourth").html());
    });
//]]>
</script>
```

There was a **i** before **document.ready** and you didn't close the function. Does it help your unresponsive page?

Comment: Thanks jrbedard. I have just realised why the $i was there and I have removed this but made no difference. The $i was there as there will be a carousel slider that is a part of the page, but at the moment I am trying to get this to work on its own. I have edited my original question with the carousel script and the prices script.